# LC-3 to Hexadecimal

Tags: c, hex, lc3

This program takes the input

```
  1283 
  5105
```

and prints out the following, I was wondering how to do it the opposite way around so to take the LC-3 instruction as the input and display it in Hexadecimal as I've been stuck on that for quite awhile. Any help would be great !

```
`add r1,r2,r3 
 and r0,r4,r5`
```

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<ctype.h>


int main(int arga, char *argb[]){
int str; //string
int firstReg=0;
int secondReg=0;
int opCode=0;
int reg=0; //register
char hexa[7]; //hexadecimal value
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(argb[1],"r"); 

    // Statement 1
    while((fscanf(fp,"%s",hexa))!=EOF){
    int x =0;
    str = 0;

    // Statement 2
    for (;x<=3;x++){
        switch(hexa[x]){
            case '0':  str = str|0;
            break;
            case '1':  str = str|1;
            break;
            case '2':  str = str|2;
            break;
            case '3':  str = str|3;
            break;
            case '4':  str = str|4;
            break;
            case '5':  str = str|5;
            break;
            case '6':  str = str|6; 
            break;
            case '7':  str = str|7;
            break;
            case '8':  str = str|8; 
            break;
            case '9':  str = str|9; 
            break;
            case 'a':  str = str|10; 
            break;
            case 'b':  str = str|11; 
            break;
            case 'c':  str = str|12; 
            break;
            case 'd':  str = str|13;
            break;
            case 'e':  str = str|14; 
            break;
            case 'f':  str = str|15; 
            break;
            default:   printf("\nInvalid hexadecimal digit %c ",hexa[x]); return 0;
        }
            if(x != 3){
                str = str <<4;
            }
    }

    opCode = str&(15<<12);
    opCode = opCode>>12;

    // Statement 3
    if(opCode == 5){

        printf("and");
        reg= str&(7<<9);
        reg= reg>>9;
        printf(" r%d",reg);

        firstReg =str & (7<<6);
        firstReg= firstReg>>6;
        printf(", r%d",firstReg);

        secondReg = str &(7);
        printf(", r%d",secondReg);
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Statement 4
    if(opCode == 1) {

        printf("add");

        reg= str&(7<<9);
        reg= reg>>9;
        printf(" r%d",reg);

        firstReg =str & (7<<6);
        firstReg= firstReg>>6;
        printf(", r%d",firstReg);

        secondReg = str &(7);
        printf(", r%d",secondReg);
        printf("\n");
    }
        }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you reading hexadecimal numbers as strings? Why not just read them as hexadecimal numbers directly into an integer variable?

Comment: Would you know a way of reading the LC-3 input and printing out the Hexadecimal values ? that's what I'm stuck on

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it just made sense for me to use switch that's why :/

Comment: What you want is basically to create a very simple *assembler* program. Without labels and with a very limited subset of the instructions (like no jumping etc.) then the hard part is the parsing of each line. Please search for parsing in relation to assemblers and you should find plenty of subjects to read.